# When and how to use Window Functions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, over-clause

I've been learning Window Functions (e.g., `OVER`, `RANK`, `PARTITION BY` clauses) in PostgreSQL but am still confused when and how to use them and what would the resulted outputs mean?

Does anyone have some summarised explanations on them?

EXAMPLE: [`OVER()`and`RANK()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmIlw.jpg)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are looking at as far as documentation on window functions in postrges?

Comment: an example of OVER and RANK clauses has been uploaded @RossBush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you one simple example where you can use `rank`.

Lets say you have the `student_marks` table and you have one test for each class. (Class 1, class 2, .. test with marks for each student in single table, for simplicity all data is considered in one table)

If you now want to give the result to the student for each class (highest marks yields the 1st number and so on) then you can use `rank` as follows:

```
Rank() over (partition by class order by marks desc) -- student_rank_in_class
```

Here,

- `Partition by class` - means rank should be given per class.
- `Order by marks desc` - means in each class, highest mark student (`marks desc`) should be given 1st rank, then second highest should be given 2nd rank and so on.

Hope, This explanation will give you some glimplse about `rank` window function.

Comment: Hi Popeye thank you for the explanation. I am also wondering that can I use ``GROUP BY`` instead of ``PARTITION BY`` to answer this question (by slightly altering the format of query) since I find they similar?

Comment: Group by will group the result and will operat on aggregate functions which results in less than or equal to number of rows in your table based on which columns you did group by. If you group by class only then you will get one row per class. You will not get each student data in that case.

Comment: Lovely!! I understand now. Thank you